# Javascript Menu

Tags: javascript, forms, effect, slide

I am working on a page, which has a link which reads "update". When users click this link, I would like a form to use a slide effect and appear underneath the link. When the form is submitted, it updates the db, and the menu vansihes.

I know this can be done with javascript, but I am not sure how to implement it.

Much thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, use [jquery](http://jquery.com/), it will be simpler and compliant cross browser.

Appearing with a slide effect can be done with [Jquery UI](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/).

```
$("div").click(function () {
      $(this).show("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
});
```

Updating the db assynchronously can be done using the [post method](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post):

```
$.post("/action.php", { },
      function(data){
    }, "text");
```

... but you can also simply post the form synchronously and refresh the page.

Comment: seems almost perfect, but can you explain it a bit furthur? is "div" the div id? Also, how to I get a form to appear with this effect

Comment: div is how you identify the element you want to appear. read up a bit on jquery selectors to get this. You've got stuff here: http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors  and all over google. If you want to show a form like this, wrap the form in a div with an id and call the function on this div. Of course at the begining the form needs to be hidden (style='display:none')

Comment: You don't need jQuery UI... jQuery is enough - plus a call to animate()

Comment: You can do without just using the show('slow') function, but it's always nice to know jquery UI

Answer (score 0):

You should consider a javascript library such as jQuery to help you achieve this. 
Basically what you need is to create a DIV at disired position and hide it when the document finishes loading then add events for the menu click

With jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('#myDivId').hide(); //Hiding the div

        $('#updadeLinkId').click(function() {
             $('#myDivId').slideToggle('slow'); //This is the slide effect
        });

    });
```

The jQuery library can be downloadeds at http://www.jquery.com/

Comment: I'm not a big fan of  $('#myDivId').hide(); on document ready because it might display the div and then hide it... which is not really pretty for the end user

Comment: That has never happened to me. Good to know

Answer (score -1):

May I also add that you will need to ensure the page works without javascript as well, many users, myself included surf with javascript disabled. And I personally would abandon your site if key functionality was sacrificed so you can make the page look prettier.

Answer (score -3):

You can do this using JQuery or AJAX toolkit on ASP.NET. WHIch language do you want it in?
It cannot be done in pure javascript only

Comment: Ajax is a part of javascript, stop talking rubbish.